# How can I properly implement an authentication challenge using a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I'm building a web browser and I'm really novice when it comes to networking.

I'd like to test the code sample bellow but I have no real life example to work with:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler
{
    CFDataRef exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust);

    SecTrustSetExceptions(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, exceptions);

    CFRelease(exceptions);

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

Can anyone provide a URL where I can test the code above?

**Edit:** I started a bounty because I feel exhausted. I'm in the process of finalizing the application I created and there are so many issues popping up everyday. I'd really appreciate a helping hand!

Comment: check this https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips

Answer (score -1):

@Vulkan Please check your code with this link.

http://samvermette.com

I have used this link from https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController

Comment: You are using a UIWebView. I'm interested in WKWebView.