# How can I test an authentication challenge?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, wkwebview

Dear fellow citizens of Earth.

I'm requesting a real life example where I can test the authentication challenge code snippet I found below. If it's not possible I would appreciate any suggestions on what to do so that I can validate it.

I have a feeling the code is working:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler
{
    NSString *host = webView.URL.host;

    NSString *authenticationMethod = [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod];

    if ([authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault]
        || [authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic]
        || [authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest]) {

        NSString *title = @"Authentication Challenge";

        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ requires username and password.", host];

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

            textField.placeholder = @"Username";
        }];

        [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

            textField.placeholder = @"Password";

            textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        }];

        [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Authenticate" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

            NSString *username = ((UITextField *)alertController.textFields[0]).text;

            NSString *password = ((UITextField *)alertController.textFields[1]).text;

            NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);

        }]];

        [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
        }]];

        [_delegate webView:self didReceiveAuthenticationChallengeWithAlertController:alertController];
    }
    else if ([authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {

        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
    }
    else {

        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
}
```

Love and peace to all.

Source: https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips

Older question: [How can I properly implement an authentication challenge using a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671360/how-can-i-properly-implement-an-authentication-challenge-using-a-wkwebview)

Comment: Are you asking how to write a Unittest for this code? Or how to validate directly in the UI that even the exceptional cases are working?

Comment: I need to validate the code. I don't have a server to connect to. I can't check if the code will work or not. Which are the exceptional cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would just have to set specific breakpoints in your code and then manipulate some variables in the debugger console with statements like `expr varName=@"test"` to test code like this.

The interesting part here is how to even trigger the call to `webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`

1. Use a HTTP Testing service like [HTTPBin](https://httpbin.org/) - e.g. [this](https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd) for an Basic Auth test
2. Write a simple WebServer with python, ruby etc. and test against it
3. configure the OSX-builtin Apache httpd to use Basic Auth for access, then test with the iOS Simulator against localhost. [Here's](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20001208112949174) a simple tutorial on how to configure the server. Be sure to check the comments, as some steps are outdated (e.g. the conf file is now located at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf)